# How to turn the following code into a for loop?

Tags: r

data is a df where each column is a **list** (not vector)

```
list1=sapply(data[,1], function(x) ifelse(x == "NULL", NA, x))
df1=as.data.frame(list1)
list2=sapply(data[,2], function(x) ifelse(x == "NULL", NA, x))
df2=as.data.frame(list2)
.
.
.
mytable=as.data.frame(cbind(df1,df2,....))
mytable= as.data.frame(t(mytable))

}
```

EDIT: see below for data structure. only one column shown as example, there are 1000+cols like this.

> str(data[,2])

```
List of 1
 $ LOCATIONS:List of 155
  ..$ CHILDREN                   : chr "0"
  ..$ DESCRIPTION                : chr "Home Quarter"
  ..$ DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION: NULL
  ..$ DISABLED                   : chr "0"
  ..$ HASCHILDREN                : chr "0"
  ..$ HASPARENT                  : chr "0"
  ..$ HIERARCHYPATH              : NULL
  ..$ LOCATION                   : chr "52345"
  ..$ LOCATIONSID                : chr "228"
  ..$ MTOIR                      : chr "0"
  ..$ AQUACRUSTACEANSNUM         :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"
  ..$ MQUAFISH                   : chr "0"
  ..$ MQUAFISHNUM                :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

If we wanted to convert the OP's code into a loop

```
lst1 <- vector('list', ncol(data))
for(i in seq_along(data)) {
      lst1[[i]] <- as.data.frame(sapply(data[,i], 
        function(x) ifelse(x == "NULL", NA, x)))
}

mytable <- as.data.frame(t(do.call(cbind, lst1)))
```

Comment: @Spacejelly Can you update your post with `dput(head(data))`

Comment: i think the problem is that my list is nested and is.null isn't picking up the actuall NULL values within each list element

Comment: @Spacejelly or can you show the `str(data)` to understand the structure

Comment: @Spacejelly can you please edit your code and update there so that it is more clear

Comment: it is a XML file that I read in and trying to convert it into a dataframe. my email is oorangy@gmail.com. May I send you a sample input file and code to see what's wrong please? thank you

Comment: @Spacejelly can you post the dput in a github page and then send the link

Comment: i have updated the post with the structure, thank you

Comment: the only way I found that actually did replace the NULLs with NAs was what i posted, but I don't know how to write a loop for that as it needs to be iterated 1000+ times.. than cbind them together into a df

Comment: @Spacejelly can you try the updated code in my post

Comment: It seems to be replacing with NAs now, but how do I turn it into a dataframe? it outputs as a large list with mulitiple elements

Comment: @Spacejelly when you say a data.frame as output, do you still want the output data.frame to have the same structure as before?

Comment: @Spacejelly if you wnt the same structure, use `data[] <-` (updated the post)

Comment: data[] did not seem to have done anything. I'd like each element in the list to be parsed into column. right now data is a large list with 1200 elements. I would like a df with 1200 columns, where rows would be the attributes for each element

Comment: I tried: data.frame(matrix(unlist(data), nrow=132, byrow=TRUE))
but records seem to have shifted and are not aligned

Comment: @Spacejelly It is not clear base don your structure.  I updated with your code in a loop.  Hope it works

Comment: thank you, but lst1 is still a list using the code. Can I send you my data to have a try please? I simply cannot figure out why it isn't working...

Comment: @Spacejelly it is not `lst1`.  It is the `mytable` at the end

Comment: mytable could not be produced: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 155, 158, 157, 159, 156, 160, 161

Comment: @Spacejelly I was using the same code as you showed in the post.  The change is only in the indexing in `for` loop